# Django - how to run subprocess commands on button click

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I'm currently creating (maybe recreating) a Django web application that allows the user to add multiple subprocess commands to a queue and run them.  For example the test queue may look like this:

name: directories, command: 'ls'

name: change directory, command: 'cd'

Once the user initiates the queue to begin, I want to send these commands to the server using the subprocess python module.

The user initiates the queue to begin by clicking a button.

I currently have a function in my views.py that looks like this:

```
    def start_commands(request):
        queue = TestQueue.objects.all()
        queue = list(queue.commands)
        for x in range(len(queue)):
            output = subprocess.check_output('%s' %queue[x], shell=True)
```

I also have an .html file that holds a button:

```
    <center><button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg'>Button</button></center>
```

I have no idea at all how I can execute my start_commands method on a button click. How can I do this?

Comment: In exactly the same way as any other action in Django: write a view that does what you want, and a url pattern that calls it, and get the form to submit to that url.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't understand the last part, can you elaborate a little more

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure which bit you didn't understand.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't understand the form part. Why do I need a form to submit to the url?

Comment: Because that's how buttons work. If you don't want a form, you can use a link, but a button needs a form.